# Why is slice returning an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a set of booleans.

```
const [locks, setLock] = useState([false, false, false, false]);
```

**Goal:** I am trying to change a value based on the index by slicing the old lock array.

**Issue:** If the value is 1, the last part of the array (`locks.slice(value + 1)`) is returning as empty.

Shouldn't slice returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object, so it's not like the locks array is getting changed?

```
function handleLock(event) {
      const {value} = event.currentTarget;
      const oldLock = locks[value]
      console.log(oldLock)
      const newLocks =  locks.slice(0, value).concat([!oldLock]).concat(locks.slice(value + 1));
      setLock(newLocks)
  }
```

**Broken Down**

```
function handleLock(event) {
      const {value} = event.currentTarget;
      const oldLock = locks[value]
      console.log(oldLock)
      const locks1 = locks.slice(0, value)
      const locks2 = locks.slice(value+1)
      console.log(locks2)
      const newLocks =  locks1.concat([!oldLock]).concat(locks2);
      setLock(newLocks)
  }
```

**Question:** What is causing this issue and how do I solve it?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: I found out I'm an idiot and it was just because the value is getting passed as a string. So value + 1 = 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be, `event.target.value` might be returning a `string` instead of a `number`. This would cause the sliced value to be an empty array because adding a string to number results in concatenation, not addition.

Try using `const value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);`

A suggestion would be to use spread syntax to duplicate the array then assign the value. This should make the code more readable and simpler

```
const newLocks = [...oldLocks];
newLocks[value] = !newLocks[value];
setLock(newLocks);
```